# Meteor + overflow-y: scroll makes window.scrollTo not work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, meteor, react-router

Meteor has an odd issue with smooth scrolling on iphones:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3402

This issue can be fixed easily by adding this CSS snippet

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

```
html, body {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

however, once you add overflow:

```
overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
```

then javascript scrollTo doesn't work anymore, which I'm using with react-router to scroll to top on route change:

```
const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
        history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
    }
}
```

It seems to have something to do with messing up the container height, so scrollTo isn't sure where the top is-- or at least that is my current theory.

Is there a good fix for this without giving up on smooth scrolling on iphones?

Comment: You can try doing `document.body.scrollTo(0, 0)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React-Router v4 "onUpdate" is depreciated. You can use "onEnter" property in "Routes".

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} >
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs} onEnter={handlePageChange}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Also need to modify your "handlePageChange" function as below:

```
const handlePageChange = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
        history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
    }
}
```